# Getting lat and lng from user's browser (node.js / express)

Tags: node.js, express, location

I am building a simple express / jade app and one of the requirements is to get lat and lng from the browser.

Can someone point me out in the right direction on how to do that?

Comment: This will not work because node has no access to the navigator

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 Geolocation API lets you get lat/lng from the client.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} else {
    // Geolocation is not supported by this browser
}
```

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` takes a callback function from which you can get the lat/lng like so:

```
function showPosition(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lng = position.coords.longitude; 
}
```

more about the Geolocation API can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp